# AWS CloudFormation - ignore changes in property - `ignore_changes` from Terraform equivalent?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Suppose I created

```
    CognitoUserPoolIdentityProviderGoogle:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider
      Properties:
        ProviderName: Google
        AttributeMapping:
          email: emailAddress
        ProviderDetails:
          client_id: xxxx
          client_secret: yyyy
          authorize_scopes: profile email openid phone
        ProviderType: Google
        UserPoolId:
          Ref: CognitoUserPoolUserPool
```

and later somebody updated `client_id` and `client_secret` manually to `1111` and `2222`. Rerunning CloudFormation would result in overwriting the manual change and reverting the values to `xxxx` and `yyyy`.

How do I avoid that? `AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider` is just an example - this could be any resource.

What I am looking for is basically a functionality of [ignore_changes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/resources.html#ignore_changes) in Terraform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CFN there is no "ignore changes". It is a **bad practice** to modify any resources managed by CFN, manually outside of its control. Manual changes can result in a lot of issues, one of which you are describing.

The technical term for what you are observing is a [stack drift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html). There are few ways of managing it. But the first thing you do when you suspect it is to run [drift detection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/detect-drift-stack.html) on your stack before any updates.

Since in your case the drift is not that bad, you have **two choices**:

- update CFN template manually to match the manual changes, and the update the stack
- manually modify the resources back to their original state and then apply all updates through CFN.

Comment: While I agree and avoid manual changes whenever possible, I feel that sometimes they are necessary. ASG's desired capacity or SSM's parameter value are all proper examples of that, at least in Trrraform's world.

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: There are scenarios where changes outside of CFN may be required. I'm working with an application where the deployment pipeline swaps active application instance by changing the "Weight" for load balancer target groups in the listener rules. This is fully automated, and works flawlessly to ensure there is never any interruption to service during deployments. Unfortunately this means I cannot maintain the load balancer listener rules with CFN. It would be extremely beneficial for me if I could specify in the CFN that "Weight" is to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a very frequent issue, here is another example and the way we solved it:

Having a CloudFront Distribution  declared in CloudFormation, and the attached CNAMES/Cert are managed by the app ( attached on the fly ).

So the better and automatic way we implemented to solve this 'engineering' problem is :

1. Declare all the values that are changed outside as Parameters of the template ( the list of CNAMES in the case described above )
2. Whenever a change is required => that will trigger an auto deploy pipeline
3. The pipeline would go first to retrieve the values from the currently deployed instance ( list of the CNAMES values attached by the app )
4. Then, updating the Cloudformation Template passing this list as param

Comment: Ideally you'd be managing certs/cnames with CloudFormation as well.